# Stability of cyclobutyl methyl carbocation

Tags: organic-chemistry, stability, carbocation

I know that cyclopropyl methyl carbocation is exceptionally stable compared to say, benzyl carbocation.

But I want to know how stable is cyclobutyl methyl carbocation compared to say, tertiary/secondary carbocations? Or, will it go rearrangement breaking the ring?

Comment: DOI: 10.1021/ja01473a028 <BR>
DOI: 10.1002/anie.196706661 http://thesis.library.caltech.edu/656/1/Silver_ms_1959.pdf <BR>
http://thesis.library.caltech.edu/4757/1/Cox_ef_1955.pdf The original literature arises from these two theses.

Comment: Did you mean a 3-methyl cyclopropene carbocation? I believe that's the aromatic compound that is exceptionally stable (read: still not that stable) - a regular methyl cyclopropane would be very strained, and with a charge I think it would be even less so.

Comment: @qwersjc No I am not talking about that.

Answer (score 1):

George Olah and coworkers have examined the [cyclobutyldicyclopropylmethyl](http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/ja9828962) and the [cyclobutylmethyl](http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/jo0701334) cation.

(*Yes, this is an awfully short answer and I can't really provide more information on the topic*.)

Comment: Doesn't that require to buy the content?

Comment: @Awesome Yes, unless you have access via a university or research facility.

Comment: I don't have access. Could you just tell whether it will go rearrangement breaking ring or not?