# Elimination of OH from spirocyclic compounds

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, alcohols

I was wondering, what would happen if I treated the following compound i.e. trispiro[2.1.2<sup>5</sup>.1.2<sup>9</sup>.1<sup>3</sup>]dodecane-4,8,12-triol with sulfuric acid[$\ce{H_2SO_4}$] to eliminate OH group to form double bond:

[image: molecule]

Will the double bond form? if yes then where and why? If no then what other compound will form and why?

Comment: Well, there's gonna be various rearrangements

Comment: Agree, probably a lot of 1,2-alkyl shifts.

Comment: You might get a carbonyl from a hydride shift...

Comment: Have you tried to draw the structure of a compound resulting from elimination?

Comment: @jerepierre I am really confused about what would happen. I think that there will be a ring expansion for each of those cyclopropane rings, forming a four member bridged ring. But then where would the double bonds form? Bredt's rule disallows formation of double bonds at bridgehead.

Comment: @zhe Can you explain a bit more about the formation of carbonyl be hydride shift?

Comment: Posted in chat: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47124/elimination-of-oh-from-spirocyclic-compounds       Sorry for the crappy drawing.

Comment: Ciclopropylmethanol-cyclobutanol rearrangement is  a thing.

Answer (score 4):

This question has been unanswered for quite long, and meanwhile, I have found an answer, so I wanted to share it.

On treating the compound with sulfuric acid, the $\ce{OH}$ groups will be protonated to $\ce{OH_2^+}$.

[image: protonation of the OH groups]

The $\ce{OH_2^+}$ groups are good leaving groups, so they will leave as $\ce{H_2O}$, forming carbocation.(one by one)
[image: formation of carbocation]

As cyclopropane is under significant ring strain, it will undergo ring expansion to form cyclobutane ring, which is somewhat less strained. At the same time, $\ce{H^+}$ ions will be expelled, forming double bonds. (It should also take place step by step.)
[image: formation of double bonds]

In this case I don't think that the double bond will not cause any significant barrier to the formation of the molecules, as the double bond is here the bridging bond, not at the bridgehead[formation of double bonds at bridgehead is not possible for smaller rings(<8 carbon rings), as it causes very high strain: Bredt's rule]

I have considered only elimination in this reaction scheme. Other compounds may also be formed. Feel free to post answers if you think other compounds will be formed or if you think the above mechanism is wrong in any way.

Comment: I don’t think the steps would happen to each carbon simultaneously but other than that this sounds reasonable.

Comment: @Jan Why not simultaneously?

Comment: Carbotrications seem like a far-fetched idea to me...

Comment: @CurtF. So what is your idea?

Comment: sequential not simultaneous reaction

Comment: @CurtF. Edited answer. Sequential reaction seemed to be more favourable, but when I wrote the answer, I was thinking about the end product only.

Comment: Double bonds won't form in this scenario. It still would be a triol probably.

Comment: @Zhe http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/9581/7475 ;)

Comment: @Jan I'm aware of the homoallyl cation. My issue is when it's tied by with a cyclohexyl ring. Can you look in Scifinder to see if there's migration in a spiro example?

Comment: @Zhe [L. Fitjer, M. Majewski, A. Kanschick, E. Egert, G. M. Sheldrick, *Tetrahedron Lett.* **1986**, *27*, 3603. DOI: 10.1016/S0040-4039(00)84860-1](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0040-4039(00)84860-1)

Comment: I am now genuinely confused after looking at the solution of this problem. I have seen situations where in acidic medium, if the carbocation was extremely stable, then we can leave it just like that without proceeding further into the reaction. So will aromatization provide more stability, or will the sigma resonance of the cation be enough to allow the cation to exist as it is? (I mean, I thought that in aromatic compounds is due to delocalization of the electrons, so surely more energy would be released when a sigma bond breaks...?)