# What are the major products formed by reaction of methylidene cyclopropane with HBr in CCl4 solvent?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

I am confused between two products:

1. bromomethyl cyclopropane
2. Allyl bromide

Reason for my confusion: We know CPM cation will be formed which is stabilized by dancing resonating structures why can't bromine attack at one of those dancing structures when positive charge is on end on carbon as shown in figure:

[image]

Comment: 'Dancing resonance' is a somewhat distasteful term to describe the case of cyclopropyl methyl cation. It would sound better (to me, atleast) as sigma-resonance.

Comment: Ok thanks for informing. Sir can you please clear my confusion by considering it as sigma resonance

Comment: "Distasteful" is an interesting way to put it, I'd say it is wrong. Anyway: [What is "dancing resonance"?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/65392/4945) Also related: [What is the reason for the exceptional stability of the cyclopropylmethyl carbocation?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/19090/4945) || To the formalities of the question, please include the actual question in the body, your first sentence makes no sense. Please introduce abbreviations you are using.

Comment: Also, you first structure appears incorrect to me. The primary cation should be much higher in energy than the tertiary cation.

Comment: Martin do you mean primary Cyclopropyl methyl carbocation is much much unstable than tertiary Cyclopropyl methyl carbocation?

Comment: This is not a actual question. This is my doubt sir